# Adding audio data from file to an AudioGroup to send over RTP

Tags: android, file, audio, stream, rtp

I am trying to stream audio data read from a file to a remote client over RTP. I have no clue how to add audio data from a file(mp3) to an AudioStream object. I can hear microphone data clearly, but am unable to inject file data into the stream.

Comment: I have not even been able to get the simple voice data over RTP, can you post a working example for me somewhere, it would really help me out!

Comment: Perhaps you could answer my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992712/working-rtp-stream-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a C library to be used along with an srtp implementation to stream data. Additionally, I had to also write the mixer to mix android capture card along with decoded file data stream. The whole setup is controlled from Java using jni. Currently my audio flow diagram looks like this :

**[ microphone + file data ] >>>  mixer >>> srtp >>> [ NETWORK ]**